# Dash in folder name prevents me from setting environment variables correctly?

Tags: bash, windows, mingw

I've tried several things below, but when there is a `-` in the path it seems to screw with the environment variable that I'm setting:

```
leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ export CSVFILE="/c/Users/leeand00/OneDrive\ -\ Some\ Company\ Somewhere/mycsvdb/.mycsv.sys.csv"

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ cat $CSVFILE
cat: unknown option -- \
Try 'cat --help' for more information.

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ export CSVFILE="/c/Users/leeand00/OneDrive\ \-\ Some\ Company\ Somewhere/mycsvdb/.mycsv.sys.csv"

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ cat $CSVFILE
cat: '/c/Users/leeand00/OneDrive\': Is a directory
cat: '\-\': No such file or directory
cat: 'Some\': No such file or directory
cat: 'Company\': No such file or directory
cat: Somewhere/mycsvdb/.mycsv.sys.csv: No such file or directory

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ export -- CSVFILE="/c/Users/leeand00/OneDrive\ -\ Some\ Company\ Somewhere/mycsvdb/.mycsv.sys.csv"

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ cat $CSVFILE
cat: unknown option -- \
Try 'cat --help' for more information.

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ export CSVFILE="/c/Users/leeand00/OneDrive\ -\ Some\ Company\ Somewhere/mycsvdb/\.mycsv\.sys\.csv"

leeand00@somehost MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb (develop)
$ cat $CSVFILE
cat: unknown option -- \
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: `export CSVFILE="/c/Users/leeand00/OneDrive - Some Company Somewhere/mycsvdb/.mycsv.sys.csv"; cat "$CSVFILE"`

Comment: @muru I'm aware that it works if you do that and put quotes around it, but the script I'm using doesn't do that.

Comment: Then the script is broken. See dupe.

Comment: Maybe it isn't...I grepped it for the `CSVFILE` variable name and all I got back was `"${CSVFILE}"`.  So why would that cause a problem if it's already in quotes?  Is it the curly brackets?

Comment: Without seeing the script, no saying for sure. Maybe that variable was assigned to something else, which was used unquoted.

Comment: @muru okay so you got me, the name isn't `CSVFILE` it's `KANBANFILE`, but it still doesn't allow me to use that...anyway here's the script: https://github.com/leeand00/kanban.bash/tree/feature/mingw64 I modified it from another repo so I could use it in git bash / mingw64.  the `kanban` script is the only file in the repo that I've modified.